Git on Mac OSX I unable to push to my owned branch on windows it works well
I always got an error when I tried to push my git repo.
git --no-optional-locks -c color.branch=false -c color.diff=false -c color.status=false -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false -c credential.helper=sourcetree push -v --tags origin refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master 
Pushing to "https://github.com/myName/mybranch.git"
remote: Permission to myName/mybranch.git denied to myName.
fatal: unable to access "https://github.com/myName/mybranch.git": The requested URL returned error: 403

I appreciate if somebody explain to me how can I fix this problem, I'm the owner of that branch.
On Windows it works smoothly.

I did that I created a new PAT, and set it to git. The result is the same.

I tried many times to remove the PAT of fetch and push in command line , any cause the PAT of push never removed only the fetch. I tried it in SourceTree clicked on the settings icon on the top right corner, came up a dialog I selected the Remote tab, displayed the Remote Repository path with the PAT. I simple Edit it and replace the outdated(expired) PAT with a fresh one.
